# What can cause a while loop stop?

Tags: python, while-loop

I wrote a function, that crawler(url) from web pages. there is while true, so it should keep running if nothing going run. I have a return for the whole function, it returns, so I know it stopped. I printed everything I can print for each circle, and everything looks perfect. Only the while stopped for some reason, I did not know.

The logic is I have a initial `urls[]`,

for each loop,

read a url from `urls`,

if url is not in  `parent`, put it in, else continue

crawler `links` from url using a function crawler

put url in `parent`, put `links` in `children`

put links are not in parent into `newUrl`

if reach the end of `urls`, `urls=newurls, newurls=null`

but for some reason, the loop can only run 30+ times, I checked there still lots chilren links, so I do not understand why it stops.

```
newUrl=[]
parent = []
children =[]
cloud =[]
i=0
n=0

while n<100:
    n+=1
    url = urls[i]
    if url in parent:
        i += 1
        continue
    (links,titles) = crawler(url)
    parent.append(url)
    links = list(set(links))
    children.append(",".join(links))
    cloud.append(titles)

    links = [link for link in links if link not in parent]
    newUrl= newUrl+links # is there anyone realy have a look on code
    print(len(parent)) # I guess noone did
    i += 1
    if i == len(urls):
        urls = list(set(newUrl))
        newUrl = []
        i=0
 print (n)
```

Comment: please tag you are talking about python.

Comment: I guarantee it's not for "no reason"..

Comment: @Blorgbeard definitely, there should be a reason, just we both do not find out...or I will not ask

Comment: What do you mean by "it stops"?  How do you know it stops?  What debugging have you done: have you put print statements after each line to tell you what is happening?

Comment: @GreenAsJade it is `while true`, so it should keep running. There is a return for the whole function. It returns, then I know it stops. the `print(len(parent))` count times. I print all the parameter for each circle and everything looks right. Just it stops.

Comment: What does "stops" mean?  What are the symptoms of "stops"?   Does the python process exit?   Does it sit there still running but doing nothing?   Why haven't you posted the whole code?   Is this the function crawler() that we are looking at, or something else?  If this routine we are looking at is the crawler() function, then how does it ever return?  Each time you call crawler(url), how does a result come back, since there is no return statement?   It looks like this routine would just infinitely recurse until it dies with an array index out of range error on urls[i] or runs out of memory...

Comment: @GreenAsJade return is the last line of this function, you can just put return there. I have no idea why you do not understand what means stop, let's make it simple, change it to n=0 while n<100:......n+=1. Then, the while stop when n=30+ for most test case.

Comment: We don't understand what you mean by "stop" because while loops dont "stop", they "exit". "Stop" could mean "stop producing output" or "crash" or... who knows? I'm sorry if your command of English makes this hard for you to communicate, but this is the reason why your question is being downvoted: we can't understand what the exact problem you are having is - you have not provided enough information.  You have not shared the symptoms of your problem precisely.  Rude comments in the code don't help either - the print statements I was referring to would be around the continue and crawler() calls.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that can cause your while loop to exit before n reaches 100 is an exception.

An exception could occur if your program runs out of memory, due to the infinite recursion of the crawler function calling itself (not likely in your new code with a limit of 100), or if your index i exceeds the urls array boundary, which your program logic may cause, or for some other reason that is hard to predict.